# Query All Elements in Nested JSON Array PostrgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, grafana, timescaledb

I am trying to create a query in SQL to retrieve DNS answer information so that I can visualize it in Grafana with the add of TimescaleDB. Right now, I am struggling to get postgres to query more than one element at a time. The structure of my JSON that I am trying to query looks like this:

```
{
    "Z": 0,
    "AA": 0,
    "ID": 56559,
    "QR": 1,
    "RA": 1,
    "RD": 1,
    "TC": 0,
    "RCode": 0,
    "OpCode": 0,
    "answer": [
        {
            "ttl": 19046,
            "name": "i.stack.imgur.com",
            "type": 5,
            "class": 1,
            "rdata": "i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net"
        },
        {
            "ttl": 220,
            "name": "i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net",
            "type": 1,
            "class": 1,
            "rdata": "104.16.30.34"
        },
        {
            "ttl": 220,
            "name": "i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net",
            "type": 1,
            "class": 1,
            "rdata": "104.16.31.34"
        },
        {
            "ttl": 220,
            "name": "i.stack.imgur.com.cdn.cloudflare.net",
            "type": 1,
            "class": 1,
            "rdata": "104.16.0.35"
        }
    ],
    "ANCount": 13,
    "ARCount": 0,
    "QDCount": 1,
    "question": [
        {
            "name": "i.stack.imgur.com",
            "qtype": 1,
            "qclass": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

---

There can be any number of answers, including zero, so I would like to figure out a way to query all answers. For example, I am trying to retrieve the ttl field from every index answer, and I can query a specific index, but have trouble querying all occurrences.

---

This works for querying a single index:

```
SELECT (data->'answer'->>0)::json->'ttl' 
FROM dns;
```

When I looked around, I found this as a potential solution for querying all indices within the array, but it did not seem to work and told me "cannot extract elements from a scalar":

```
SELECT answer->>'ttl' ttl
FROM dns, jsonb_array_elements(data->'answer') answer, jsonb_array_elements(answer->'ttl') ttl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jsonb_array_elements()` will give you a row for every object in the `answer` array.  You can then dereference that object:

```
select a.obj->>'ttl' as ttl, a.obj->>'name' as name, a.obj->>'rdata' as rdata
  from dns d
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(data->'answer') as a(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Do you have any resources that you would recommend for learning about cross joins? I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Yes.  Please look at `Lateral Subqueries`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html  The `cross`  means that there is no join condition which includes one copy of each row in one table paired with every row in the other table, AKA "Cartesian product".  The `lateral` is the magic.  That correlates the joined "table" with the current row of the query.  In this case, `data` is accessible when this is run, and the result of `jsonb_array_elements()` is treated like a table.  If you have another column in `dns`, then add it in the `select` list to illustrate better.